# contentScriptListener in firefox add-on cannot initiate the respective file

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've developed a firefox add on  . In main.js when I'm calling a js file using contentScriptFile it is unable to call , The function(addEventListener) get never called

```
 *** Edit 1 ***
 Sorry for missing what I actually need . 
 In get-text.js I need to send a XMLHttpRequest using GET method . If I attach my     javascript in panel.html , then I'm unable to receive  the request thereby ,
```

I'm attaching the whole file here

main.js file

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var data=require("sdk/self").data;

var button = ToggleButton({
         id: "my-button",
         label: "my button",
         icon: {
              "16": "./icon.png",
              "32": "./icon.png",
               "64": "./icon.png"
          },
         onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
         width:350,
         contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
         contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js"),
         onHide: handleHide
});
function handleChange(state) {
         if (state.checked) {
         panel.show({position: button});
  }
}

function handleHide() {
     button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

get-text.js file

```
(function(){
   var init = function() {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open("GET", "http://www.hackerearth.com/chrome-extension/events/", true);
       xhr.send();
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(xhr.readyState===4) {
               if(xhr.status===200) {
                  console.log("hello2");
                  var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  console.log(json);
               } else {
                  console.log("Status is :"+xhr.status);
              }
          }
       };
};
console.log("function passing");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log("pankaj \t");
    init();
  });
});
```

*** edit 1***

Comment: You are using addon-sdk so tag your stuff with [tag:firefox-addon-sdk] :) Making note because i saw you did this a few times :)

Comment: Does `panel.show()` appear anywhere in your add-on?

Comment: @Noitidart I will rake care of it because I didn't knew it.

Comment: @Lori I've uploaded the full main.js file

Answer (score 0):

If you need to catch the `DOMContentLoaded` event of panel's document, then drop `contentScriptFile` and include `get-text.js` from `panel.html`.

(the script will behave the same, [with a subtle difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Scripting_trusted_panel_content) regarding the `port` mechanism)

Keep in mind that `DOMContentLoaded` will be fired once, when you call the `Panel` constructor. Subsequent calls to `show`/`hide` will not trigger it.

Comment: Can he make the DOMContentLoaded fire multiple times by doing `panel.destroy()` in the `onHide` function of the panel?

Comment: @paa by the method u have told **I can call the event  but  cannot have a XMLHttpRequest to a remote server**

Comment: @user1305313 you mean that when `get-text.js` is included through `contentScriptFile` it is able to do remote XHR? @Noitidart, my point was that `show()` will not trigger `DOMContentLoaded`. Obviously when you call `destroy()` and create a new `Panel` it will fire the event.

Comment: @paa can u please give a detailed explanation or and example .. Ur thought looks like a solution to my problem

Comment: @paa also do I have to repeatedly create and destroy the panel if i had to make that pop up every time I click

Comment: @paa tell me if it ***possible to pass panel object itself in on function ***